# How to establish polymorphic relations with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, model

Using Laravel and Eloquent. I have a database that looks like this:

[image: Graphical Representation]

The `dance_performers.dance_perfomer_type` field hosts values such as `'\App\Dancer'`, `'\App\Couple'` or `'\App\Formation'`.

How would you proceed to connect the `dance_performers.dance_perfomer_id` to the different models? I am not sure how I am supposed to write the relationships in the different models.
Should I create a `\App\Performer` model which would then direct to one of the three previously mentioned?

Using polymorphic relations:

```php
class Dance extends Model {
    public function couples() {
        return $this->morphedByMany('\App\Couple', 'dance_performer');
    }
}

class Couple extends Model
{   
    public function dances() {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Dance', 'dance_performer');
    }
}
```

Currently, `$dances = \App\Dance::with('couples')->get();` only returns empty relations.
I would appreciate the help.

Comment: check my answer it will solve you problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The `type` field should be `App\ModelName` and not `\App\ModelName`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code everything is correct. I guess you don't have data in correct way in database.
Add some data like below and check.

`dances`

id - 1, name - 'Dance A'

id - 2, name - 'Dance B'

`couples`

id - 1, name - 'Couple A'

id - 2, name - 'Couple B'

`dance_performers`

id - 1, dance_id - 1, dance_performer_type - '\App\Couple', dance_performer_id - 1

id - 2, dance_id - 2, dance_performer_type - '\App\Couple', dance_performer_id - 2

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I checked the records again, and they do look good. Maybe it is worth to mention that couples and formations have many-to-many relationships with dancers. I've updated my post with a graphical representation of my db.